# How to get started with Lisp

Tags: lisp

After reading a lot of interesting articles, I decided to try out Lisp. But, where can I download 'what' to get started with Lisp?

Lisp wiki page also doesn't have any official website.

What are the dedicated lisp resources?

Comment: FYI: Lisp is a family of languages, much like C/C++/Pascal/C#/Java are all Algol languages. Lisp runs in two major dialects, Scheme and Common Lisp. Scheme has a multitude of minor dialects.

Comment: I love to solve Algorithm based problems. Why lisp is not called Algol Language?

Comment: It's a different family. Look it up on wikipedia. Mainstream languages are all descended from Algol. Lisp was before Algol. Further, it's based off what's known as the untyped lambda calculus. Do not attach too much importance to the name.

Comment: Typically, to get started with Lisp, you type an opening parenthesis, and then add some stuff, and eventually close the parenthesis. Then you give some indication that you want to submit this for evaluation, and watch what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Land of Lisp](http://landoflisp.com/) is also a great resource as well as its companion web site [lisperati](http://lisperati.com/)

One of the interesting lisp dialects these days is [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) - which runs on the JavaVM and can very well interface with existing Java code.

Answer (score 9):

[Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) by Peter Seibel is an amazing way to start learning Common Lisp and what got me started writing useful code on day 1.

What dialects are you interested in? What are your goals?

Comment: I am C++ & Java programmer, but I really dont like the constrains &  the way they force me to think about a particular matter(I cannt clarify it :D ). I was looking for something different(I don't know exactly what), but, I think Lisp is going to give me a different flavor about approaching a problem.

Comment: I really dont know much about the dialects.Basically I like to solve algorithm based problems. What do you suggest? I like to go for the core, rather then going for a hybrid one.

Comment: I think PCL does an awesome job of showing why Lisp is cool and includes walkthroughs of 'real world' projects, like an MP3 streaming server and a binary data parser. He assumes you know other languages, so you're good to go.

Comment: What are the dialects for? It is something like different implementation of pythons?(JPython, IronPython). Do the dialects vary in usages?

Comment: @iamcreasy Dialects are more than just different implementations, they are different languages. They are similar enough to be seen as belonging to the same "family" of languages, but you generally can't take one dialect's code and run it with another dialect's parser. The most well-known dialects are Common Lisp, Scheme, and Clojure. Common Lisp has many implementations that can inter-operate (like JPython and IronPython). Scheme is more fragmented, with each implementation coming up with its own way of doing basic things like package management. I have no experience with Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest IMHO is to start with [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/), very capable dialect of Lisp with nice IDE and a lot of [documentation and learning materials](http://racket-lang.org/learning.html) for any level.

Racket was initially created as a tool for learning programming, but grew into full-feature language with IDE and exhaustive set of libraries for different tasks.

You can do web apps, as well as stand-alone GUI apps right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with finding a good IDE. In my short time with LISP I used [Lispworks](http://www.lispworks.com/).